# Azure DevOps pipeline task to update a file and check-in TFS

Tags: git, powershell, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using the Azure Dev OPS to trigger the build and deploy. I have angular code in GIT branch from which the build will be triggered and based on build# I need to update a file in TFS and check-in the same.

I have added the PowerShell task to read the build# from GIT branch. But I don't know the further steps to update the file and check-in the same in TFS branch.

Please suggest PowerShell commands to achieve the ablove mentioned tasks.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Thanks Leo. Just now saw your response will try and let you know.

Comment: I tired running the below command in Powershell but it says unknown command "GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=5.0&branch={BranchName}&$top=1
" please let me know the exact command .

Comment: It seems you are not familiar with the API, I will provide you with a complete code when I have time.

Comment: I have used the following script to access the file

####Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://dev.azure.com/*********/CIO_SMT_Project/_apis/tfvc/items?path=$/CIO_SMT_Project/INSPIRE_1B_P2/******.CIO.SMT/BPOSE_WebApp/Deal/LandingPage.aspx -Method Get########

Not able to access the file even though I've allowed the scripts to access the OAuth

Do we need to specify the username and password in the body of the request object ? or Can't it have access on its own since we are running from Azure pipeline ?

Comment: I've tried the url from the browser I could able to download the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure DevOps pipeline task to update a file and check-in TFS

You could invoke the REST API [Pushes - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#rename-a-file) to update the file and check-in the same in TFS branch with powershell scripts.

1. Go to the Agent Phase and select Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token. See [Use the OAuth token to access the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=vsts#use-the-oauth-token-to-access-the-rest-api):
   [image]
2. Add a PowerShell task in your build pipeline to **get the latest commit on the branch** you want to update the file and check-in:

   ```
   GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=5.0&branch={BranchName}&$top=1
   ```
3. update the file and check-in the same in TFS branch via REST API:

   ```
   POST https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes?api-version=5.0
   ```

Body (application/json):

```
{
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/$(BranchName)",
      "oldObjectId": "[step 2 commit ID]"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Added a few more items to the task list.",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "edit",
          "item": {
            "path": "/tasks.md"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "# Tasks\n\n* Item 1\n* Item 2\n* Item 3\n* Item 4\n\nIf you need to add more, update this file and add them!",
            "contentType": "rawtext"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As the test result:

[image]

Note:

- You need to parse quotes if file content contains quotes (\"test\"),
  the same as other special charters.
- Use the [Repositories - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to get the `repositoryId`.

Hope this helps.